# Hide div when scroll near bottom using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code to show div when scrolling to a specific height. now I want to hide that div when near the bottom section.

```js
jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
  myID = document.getElementById("section-532-56");

  var myScrollFunc = function () {
    var y = window.scrollY;

    if (y >= 200) {
      myID.className = "gevity-product-bottom-sticky show";
    } else {
      myID.className = "gevity-product-bottom-sticky hide";
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the 500 number to the correct value for your project.

```js
if (y >= 200 && y <= 500) {
  myID.className = "gevity-product-bottom-sticky show";
} else {
  myID.className = "gevity-product-bottom-sticky hide";
}
```

Comment: You just need to use 3 backticks ``` (before and after code) and not spam them while adding a code block!

Comment: Cheers Manas, my internet connection is slow at times so there is sometimes a delay. Apologise

Comment: No problem, I was just mentioning.